# Something is wrong with Emmet in Visual Studio Code

Tags: emmet, visual-studio-code

After the last update, Emmet is working in some different (incorrect) way.

If I'm typing usual code in Emmet syntax like:

```
.row>.col*2
```

and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it's not working.

If I type:

```
h1{Some title}
```

and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it's also not working, but if I put the cursor inside brackets, and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> — in this case it's going to work.

This is my Visual Studio Code configuration:

```
"editor.fontSize": 12,
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
"editor.wrappingIndent": "indent",
"editor.minimap.enabled": true,
"workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off",
"window.openFoldersInNewWindow": "on",
"workbench.welcome.enabled": false,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
"[stylus]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": false,
        "comments": false,
        "strings": false
    }
},
"emmet.preferences": {
    "stylus.valueSeparator": ": "
},
"git.enableSmartCommit": true
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 47):

As of version 1.15.1 this worked for me:

Open up your preferences and add in

`"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true`

It seems <kbd>Tab</kbd> is no longer associated with Emmet.

If you are on `v1.33.0` or newer, you can also open up the preferences and type in something like `trigger expansion` and it's just a simple toggle now. Of course, you can still do the above in the `settings.json` file as well.

Comment: Thanks! To be more specific, on windows, you need to go to File > Preferences > Settings > Type in "Launch" > click on "Edit in settings.json"

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me :) I'm using macOS by the way.

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into this same problem, but I have a slightly different reason for it. Not only did I need to set **triggerExpansionOnTab to true**, but I also needed to **set the included languages in the settings.json** file.

In my case, Emmet was not activated for *blade.php* files. So, I needed to add `"blade":"html"` within the `includedLanguages` section.

Full example:

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascript",
    "vue-html": "html",
    "php": "html",
    "blade": "html",
}
```

Adding this might also help:

```
"emmet.useNewEmmet": true,
```

Answer (score 2):

I read an update review and found out that Visual Studio Code had the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key removed to expand the abbreviations [Emmet 2.0 in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/08/07/emmet-2.0).

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> is no longer available for Emmet as [Lukavis mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672355/something-is-wrong-with-emmet-in-visual-studio-code/45672589#45672589). It is sad, but you can still:

1. Go to menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts*
2. Search for "emmet"
3. Find *editor.emmet.action.expandAbbreviation*
4. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> ***or whatever you like*** key bindings...

Comment: This is somewhat wrong. See Brad Ahrens' answer for `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab"` which will allow you to use tab again.