# I can't not use Emmet keyboard shortcut

Tags: emmet

I edit some Emmet keyboard shortcut
after update, I can not use any Emmet keyboard shortcut
vscode keep alert 'command 'editor.emmet.action.balanceOut' not found
Let me know what do I do to use Emmet keyboard shortcut again

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672355/something-is-wrong-with-emmet-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Something is wrong with Emmet in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672355/something-is-wrong-with-emmet-in-visual-studio-code)